# Deformat text in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to remove the formatting from text in discord.py - adding \ before *'s, ```'s etc. I have not yet been able to come up with a perfect solution.
Can anyone tell me what I could use?
I use discord.py and python 3

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried, a sample of the input, the expected output and the actual output. Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

If this is in a command you can use [`commands.clean_content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.clean_content)

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg: commands.clean_content(fix_channel_mentions=False, use_nicknames=True, escape_markdown=True, remove_markdown=False)):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

All params are kwarg only and optional, for more info [see the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.clean_content)

If you want to escape markdown for some other text (e.g. from an API), you can use [`utils.escape_markdown`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.escape_markdown)

```py
import discord
text = "Hello my name is **Wasi**"
print(discord.utils.escape_markdown(text))
# 'Hello my name is \*\*Wasi\*\*'
```

There is also [`utils.escape_mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.escape_mentions) for removing mentions

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py provides a utility function: [discord.utils.escape_markdown](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.utils.escape_markdown)
This converts:

````
#```python
#print("hello")
#```
#**bold** *italics*
````

into

```
#\`\`\`python
#print("hello")
#\`\`\`
#\*\*bold\*\* \*italics\*
```